# Bootstrap Navigation bar does not open and links do not show up

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a nav bar with links and a collapsible menu for small screens. However, I am having two issues:

1. On normal size screens, the links do not show up
2. On mobile, when clicking the menu open button, the menu opens but collapses immediately.

Here is a link to my code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u7c03g2/). Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta viewport="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Page name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>



<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Page Name</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thetarget">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="thetarget">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="page1.html">txt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">txt1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">txt2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you override things with some ancient css, nothing is gonna show up...

Comment: Yep, you should never have two versions of the same thing on the same site. I suggest you remove the "ancient" version (2.3.2), and check that all classes are up to date for 4.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the navbar bootstrap [here](https://codepen.io/abidishajia/pen/aEebZW?editors=1010) using the w3school page. I changed the script tags in the head tag and code a bit. Hope this helps.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thetarget">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Page Name</a>
    </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="thetarget">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li> <a class="nav-link" href="page1.html">txt</a> </li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">txt1</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">txt2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```